# How to make filling (semi) transparent?

Tags: plotting, filling

I want to make the filling between lines 2 and 3 semi-transparent so that the viewer can see there is another filling between lines 1 and 3 in the background. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

`LogLogPlot[{8/x, 6/x, 4/x}, {x, 3, 5}, Filling -> {{1 -> { {3}, Cyan}}, {2 -> { {3}, Yellow}}}]`

[image]

Comment: You could replace `Yellow` with `Directive[Yellow, Opacity[.4]]`, it ends up looking green though and isn't entirely clear it is transparent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Colors interact with each other. A `HatchFilling` would provide more visual differentiation.

```
LogLogPlot[{8/x, 6/x, 4/x}, {x, 3, 5}
 , Filling -> {
   {1 -> {{3}, Directive[Lighter@Cyan, HatchFilling[π/4, 4, 14]]}}
   , {2 -> {{3}, Directive[Opacity[0.4], Yellow]}}
   }
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Note that `Opacity` can take a color without the need to use `Directive`, e.g., `Opacity[0.4, Yellow]`

Comment: Didn't know that, Thanks @BobHanlon.